# Jquery If Does Not Exist Show Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies, modal-dialog

I'm trying to set up a modal on my website. I want it so if a cookie does not exist, the modal pops up. The user will then be able to choose whether to stop the modal from popping up for the rest of the session, or to prevent it from showing again indefinitely. So I'd like the script to check if the cookie exists, and then take the necessary actions. I'm admittedly bad at Jquery but I'm in a rush... My code:

```
    var points_modal = $.cookie('points-modal');
    if (typeof points_modal == "undefined" {
        $('.fade').css( "display", "block !important");
        $('.modal-back').css( "display", "block !important");
    } else {
        $('.fade').show(); // hidden or cookie is not set, set just in case
        $('.modal-back').show();
        $.removeCookie('points-modal'); // prevent multiple instances
        $.cookie('points-modal', 'show'); // update (or set) the cookie
    }
    if (points_modal == "never") {
        $('fade').hide();
        $('.modal-back').hide();
    }
    //Clicks
    $('never').click(function () {
        $.removeCookie('points-modal');
        $.cookie('points-modal', 'never', {
            expires: 999
        });
    });
});
```

The modal initially has display:hidden. Also, is there any way I can get the fadeIn effect to work? Thanks.

View the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rrKcE/)

Comment: @Edgar Villegas Alvarado Well, neither the .fade nor the .modal-back div's are showing when I load the page.

Comment: on line 2 you're missing the end `)` for the if statement. and you don't need important for the css

Comment: Updated with the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple syntax and other problems, try

```
var points_modal = $.cookie('points-modal');
//show the modal if the cookie is not set to never
if (points_modal != "never") {
    $('.fade').show();
    $('.modal-back').show();
}

$('#never').click(function () {
    $.removeCookie('points-modal');
    $.cookie('points-modal', 'never', {
        expires: 999
    });
    //hid the modal
    $('.fade').hide();
    $('.modal-back').hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xWF64/)

Comment: It's beautiful, tbh. Thanks.